# In R, how do I test that two functions have the same definition?

Tags: r, function, equality, equivalent

I have two functions, `f` and `g`, which have the same definition:

```
f <- function(x) { x + 1 }
g <- function(x) { x + 1 }
```

However, the `identical` function considers them different:

```
identical(f, g)
FALSE
```

I presume this is because they occupy different areas in memory; `identical(f, f)` gives `TRUE`.

I am only interested in testing that the functions having the same *definition*; is there another function I can use for this?

The behaviour should be:

```
sameDefinition(f, f)
TRUE

sameDefinition(f, g)
TRUE

sameDefinition(f, function(x) { x + 1 })
TRUE

sameDefinition(f, function(x) { x + 3 }) 
FALSE 

# Equivalent, but different definitions
sameDefinition(f, function(x) { x + 2 - 1 }) 
FALSE
```

Comment: You can try `all.equal` (found while reading `?identical` in the see-also part)

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks.

Comment: A function consists of more than just a body. Even the body has things in addition to the text. If you want to compare only the text in the body try `identical(as.character(body(g)), as.character(body(f)))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Long version of my comment:

Quote of `?identical` doc:

> **See Also**
>
> `all.equal` for descriptions of how two objects differ;

In the all.equal doc there's:

> Do not use all.equal directly in if expressions—either use
>   isTRUE(all.equal(....)) or identical if appropriate.

So you don't really need a function, you can write `isTRUE(all.equal(f,g))` and be done with your task.

Answer (score 5):

You could `deparse` the functions and then check if they are identical:

```
identical(deparse(f),deparse(g))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Tensibai, you can use the `all.equal` function. A wrapper is required since `all.equal` will return a character vector when the objects are not equal.

```
sameDefinition <- function(x, y) { 

    stopifnot(is.function(x), "x must be a function")
    stopifnot(is.function(y), "y must be a function")

    identical(all.equal(x, y), TRUE)
}
```

Examples:

```
sameDefinition(f, g)
TRUE

sameDefinition(f, function(x) { x + 2 - 1 })
FALSE
```

Comment: Why not using directly isTRUE as per all.equal documentation ?

Comment: `isTRUE` is just `identical(TRUE, x)` - I suppose either approach is valid.

Comment: `identical(TRUE, x)` is not the same as `x == TRUE`. Try them with `x <- "TRUE"`. And you should use `TRUE` instead of `T`, since `T` can be redefined and `TRUE` cannot.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that - updated the answer accordingly.